# Edmodo android image cropper, fix aspect ratio

Tags: android, crop

I've some problem using edmodo/cropper library on android lollipop. 
My app should take some pictures, and after each picture is taken, user should crop a square image.
this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.newapicamera.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer" />

<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/footer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

and this is how i launch library for crop after picture is taken;

```
crop_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
mCameraDevice.close();
mTextureView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
crop_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
crop_view.setFixedAspectRatio(true);
crop_view.setAspectRatio(dpWidth, dpWidth);
```

I have the sequent problem:

- with this code, the crop is a stripe high as screen
- if i remove fixed aspect ratio, the aspect ratio i've is ignored, and i obtain a rectangular crop.
  So, how can i do to force crop to a square?

Comment: Checkout [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper), lots of improvements over edmodo.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and the below solution works for me:

```
cropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(true);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cropImageView.setAspectRatio(7, 7);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

**This problem is a bug and now you can use new version and this problem is fixed.**
**new version is 2.0.0** at this time and unfortunately does not mentioned on cropper wiki.